# How to close a file dialog box in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I open a file dialog box by node.js as

```
await page.goto('https://www.example.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
let a = await page.$('#file');
a.click();
```

where the html code is like

```
<form action="">
<input type="file" id="file" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

`a.click()` open a dialog box in the browser to choose the file. When the dialog box is opened the first file is already selected, and if pressing `enter`, the dialog box will be closed.

I wonder if there is a possibility in `Node.js` to close the file dialog box programmatically?

In other words, I want to automatically submit the form as

```
let a = await page.$('#file');
a.click();
// HERE close the opened dialog box
let b = await page.$('#submit');
b.click();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot open the dialog to select the file. Instead you have to use [elementHandle.uploadFile](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandleuploadfilefilepaths) to handle the file upload:

```js
let a = await page.$('#file');
await a.uploadFile('PATH/TO/YOUR.FILE');

let b = await page.$('#submit');
b.click();
```